# Month missing in getting dates for year if date is not available in month

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I am trying to get the dates for next year after provided date with following code

```
var dateArray = new Array();
dateArray.push(date);
for(var i=1;i<12;i++){
    dateArray.push(new Date(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth()+i,date.getDate()));
}
console.log(dateArray)
```

It is working fine if I select dates between 1-28 but when I select any date which is not available for any upcoming month it moves to next month.

what should happen here is I should be getting last date of month for which selected date is not available

Comment: `I am trying to get the dates for next year after provided date`. I'm sorry, what? Can you provide some expected inputs and ouputs?

Comment: I provide a input date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Date` object type handles overflow of the day of the month by incrementing the month, just as you said. To do what you want, you need to add an `if` statement that checks if the date is correct, and fixes it if it isn't.

```js
var date = new Date(2015, 2, 30);

var dateArray = new Array();
dateArray.push(date);
for (var i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
  dateArray.push(new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + i, date.getDate()));

  // check if the day of the month is correct.
  // If it isn't, we know that it overflowed into the next month
  if(dateArray[i].getDate() !== date.getDate()) {
    // setting the day to 0 will set it to the last day of the previous month
    dateArray[i].setDate(0);
  }

}
console.log(dateArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to gat last day of particular month and year

```
function daysInMonth (month,year) {    
    return new Date(year, month+1, 0).getDate();
};
```